# Adding a Set of JTextFields to a Panel at Runtime, Different Layout Manager

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

I am trying to make a set of two JTextfields (side by side) appear inside of a panel when a button is clicked. The problem is that something like Flowlayout will make my textfields move all over the place (they line up in a single row or column), and Gridlayout makes the textfields far too big. I have investigated Springlayout and Grouplayout, but these layouts don't seem to have a straightforward way to add a component at runtime (plus the code is really messy looking to me, as seen in the example below).

This is an example of what I am trying to achieve with the layout...run the code and pay attention to how the JTextfields react when you resize the window (the add set of fields button doesn't work, because I am unsure of how to add components to the panel with the Grouplayout in place):

#### GoodLayout.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.GroupLayout;
import javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class GoodLayout extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTextField textField;
    private JTextField textField_1;
    private JTextField textField_2;
    private JTextField textField_3;
    private JTextField textField_4;
    private JTextField textField_5;

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    GoodLayout frame = new GoodLayout();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public GoodLayout() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 383, 328);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));

        JButton buttonAddFields = new JButton("+ Add Set of Fields +");
        buttonAddFields.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.out.println("Add a set of fields to the panel");

            }
        });
        contentPane.add(buttonAddFields, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        contentPane.add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        textField = new JTextField();
        textField.setColumns(10);

        textField_1 = new JTextField();
        textField_1.setColumns(10);

        textField_2 = new JTextField();
        textField_2.setColumns(10);

        textField_3 = new JTextField();
        textField_3.setColumns(10);

        textField_4 = new JTextField();
        textField_4.setColumns(10);

        textField_5 = new JTextField();
        textField_5.setColumns(10);
        GroupLayout gl_panel = new GroupLayout(panel);
        gl_panel.setHorizontalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 518, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(textField_3, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 518, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(textField_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(textField_5, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 518, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                    .addContainerGap())
        );
        gl_panel.setVerticalGroup(
            gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(gl_panel.createSequentialGroup()
                    .addContainerGap()
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(textField_1, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField_2, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(textField_3, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addPreferredGap(ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                    .addGroup(gl_panel.createParallelGroup(Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(textField_4, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addComponent(textField_5, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addContainerGap(287, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        panel.setLayout(gl_panel);
    }

}
```

The important bit in the code above is the actionPerformed method...I would really like to find a simple solution that looks good (GUI layout-wise) when the button is clicked and a pair of textfields appear. Maybe there is a better layout for this? I used the Eclipse plugin WindowBuilder to build the code above, and I have tried all of the different layout options that seemed reasonable to try.

Any ideas or tricks about how to better tackle this problem are appreciated

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not discard the `GroupLayout` manager -- it is a very capable layout manager
and is one of the few managers that does things properly.
However, it is not suited for dynamic layout constructions due to the
way the layout is built. We would have to completely redo our layout and
do ad hoc calculations.

For this, we can easily use `MigLayout`. `MigLayout` is a third-party layout
manager that also does things properly. It is easy to use and very powerful.

```
package com.zetcode;

import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class GoodLayout2 extends JFrame {

    private JPanel pnl;

    public GoodLayout2() {

        initUI();

        setTitle("MigLayout solution");
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    private void initUI() {

        JButton addBtn = new JButton("Add");
        addBtn.addActionListener(new AddAction());

        pnl = new JPanel(new MigLayout("ins dialog, wrap 2"));
        pnl.add(addBtn, "span 2, center");
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10), "pushx, growx");
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10), "pushx, growx");
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10));
        pnl.add(new JTextField(10), "pushx, growx");

        add(pnl);
        pack();

    }

    private class AddAction extends AbstractAction {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            pnl.add(new JTextField(10));
            pnl.add(new JTextField(10), "pushx, growx");
            pnl.doLayout();
            pnl.repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                GoodLayout2 ex = new GoodLayout2();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I have placed the button to the north part of the window, since the code
is then slightly less complicated.

[image: Good layout]

Comment: Thank you so much! Your code is so readable and concise. This solves my problem perfectly :)